# How do I make zeitgeist work in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux

I've been trying to setup Zeitgeist on my Gnome-shell system for a couple of days, but I'm yet to get it to work. I've done everything I could think of, i.e. installing zeitgeist from [extra], as well as libqzeitgeist. I've also installed all Gnome extensions created by Seif (https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/seif), since they're the reason I'm installing the package in the first place. I've tried running "zeitgeist-daemon --replace" and then "gnome-shell --replace", but nothing seems to work. According to Der Harm's wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/User:Der_harm#Gnome_Zeitgeist), the Zeitgeist daemon doesn't need to be explicitly started, but even if it was, I don't know how to do it (since it's not in /etc/rc.d, I bet adding "zeitgeist" to my rc.conf wouldn't do any good either). I can't believe there isn't a very simple setup here, please help me see what I'm missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was installing `zeitgeist-datasources` and `zeitgeist-datahub` from the **AUR** and this was working.

For the autostart I added an entry in `gnome-session-properties`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've installed zeitgeist-datasources and added zeitgeist-daemon to gnome-session-properties and restarted. Acoording to the system monitor, the daemon is running, but is always asleep. The journal also doesn't seem to be working yet. :-/

Comment: Sorry I forget one package. should work with zeitgeist-datahub

Comment: Awesome! Now it's working. zeitgeist-daemon was already collecting data, but the datahub was necessary in order to show them on the Overlay. Thank you so much!